# Multiple log file and log rotation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, log-rotation

I'm a newbie in ruby on rails. I struggled to find the solution for writing multiple logs and the daily rolling file appender.

The output will be like that: (logfile in folder {my project}/log)

```
db_access.log
db_access.log.20200513
...
user_operator.log
user_operator.log.20200513
...
```

And I have found a simple solution.

Comment: you must need to understand how to use SO editor.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `gem 'multi_logger'` in Gemfile and run `bundle install`.
2. Create file `logger.rb` in `/config/initializers` and add below code

   MultiLogger.add_logger('user_operation', shift_age: 'daily', shift_period_suffix: '%Y%m%d')
   MultiLogger.add_logger('db_access', shift_age: 'daily', shift_period_suffix: '%Y%m%d')
3. Now, you can write log in your project

   Rails.logger.user_operation.info 'your_message'

   Rails.logger.db_access.info 'your_message'

(write log in level info) 

You can also customize your log by adding other options: `logdev`, `shift_age`, `shift_size`, `level`, `progname`, `formatter`, `datetime_format`, `shift_period_suffix`

Comment: Please add this comment in your answer.